# Result of request not show in Template Toolkit

Tags: perl, dancer

I have an SQLite database with computer table. I have two rows in computer table.

I want to get all computers and show the results in *Template Toolkit* template.

This is the
[`Dancer2`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2)
controller code, which uses
[`Dancer2::Plugin::Auth::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2::Plugin::Auth::Tiny)
and
[`Dancer2::Plugin::DBIC`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2::Plugin::DBIC)

```
get '/listallmachine' => needs login => sub {
    my $computerRs = schema('default')->resultset('Computer');
    my @computers = $computerRs->all;
    template 'listmachine' => {
        'title'     => 'Liste des machines',
        'msg'       => get_flash(),
        'computers' => \@computers
    };
 };
```

And for the template:

```
[% FOREACH c IN computers %]
    <tr>
        <td>[% c.ip %]</td>
        <td>[% c.uuid %]</td>
    </tr>
[% END %]
```

Configuration file:

```
# configuration file for development environment

# the logger engine to use
# console: log messages to STDOUT (your console where you started the
#          application server)
# file:    log message to a file in log/
logger: "console"

# the log level for this environment
# core is the lowest, it shows Dancer2's core log messages as well as yours
# (debug, info, warning and error)
log: "core"

# should Dancer2 consider warnings as critical errors?
warnings: 1

# should Dancer2 show a stacktrace when an 5xx error is caught?
# if set to yes, public/500.html will be ignored and either
# views/500.tt, 'error_template' template, or a default error template will be used.
show_errors: 1

# print the banner
startup_info: 1

plugins:
      DBIC:
        default:
          dsn: dbi:SQLite:dbname=papt.db
```

The template shows nothing. Have you any idea?

Comment: Have you checked what's in `@computers`?

Comment: Yes this is my computer data: the result of the request. If I don't use the template it's work...

Comment: Ok. I thought my answer (below) would help, but it seems that there is more going on here. What happens if you eliminate the Template Toolkit and just loop through the array in your Perl code? What do you get if you include `[% computers.size %]` in your template? Or `[% computers.0 %]`?

Comment: I have test [% computers.size %] and  [% computers.0 %] and show nothing. But if I replace the template line by "return $computers[0]->get_column("ip")" it's work... I get the ip adress of the first computer.

Comment: Please update your question with the answers to these questions.

Comment: What about `$computers[0]->ip`?

Comment: It's work too. My web framework is Dancer 2.

Comment: Please add your `Dancer2` config file to your question. It seems very strange to have a result set called `User` that contains information about computers.

Comment: I have made a guess at the modules you're using and edited your question to list them. Please check that my guesses are correct, and add any more that I have missed.

Comment: Yes I have fix this mistake. The module is correct. Thanks.

Comment: It's *very* suspicious that something as fundamental as the table name was wrong in your original code. I think you'll have to `use Data::Dumper` and `print Dumper \@computers`, preferably to a file. I'll wait to see the output of that.

Comment: I have test an other table name and this is the reason for User instead Computer in original post. The content of dumper is here: https://ufile.io/igs9c  my data is present.

Comment: Do you have a `<table>` tag in the template? If that's not there your browser might not display the table. But the data would be there in the page source.

Answer (score 2):

You need to take a reference to `@computers`.

```
get '/listallmachine' => needs login => sub {
    my $computerRs = schema('default')->resultset('User');
    my @computers=$computerRs->all;
    template 'listmachine' => {
        'title'     => 'Liste des machines',
        'msg'       => get_flash(),
        'computers' => \@computers, # Note: Take reference here.
    };
};
```

**Update:** Ok, I think I can explain this now.

In a comment, you say that `get_flash()` returns "a Hashmap" (which, I assume, means "a hash"). Let's assume that it returns a hash with two key/value pairs (`one => 1` and `two => 2`). That means that the hash you send to `template` will look like this:

```
{
  title     => 'Liste des machines',
  msg       => one => 1, two => 2,
  computers => \@computers
};
```

But that's all just a flat list. Perl will interpret it like this:

```
{
  title       => 'Liste des machines',
  msg         => 'one',
  1           => 'two',
  2           => 'computers',
  \@computers => undef,
};
```

Do you see what has happened? Because of the multiple values returned from `get_flash()` your key/value pairs have all got out of line. And you no longer have a hash key called `computers`. That's why the template can't find a variable called `computers` - it no longer exists.

The fix is to take a reference to the hash that is returned from `get_flash()`:

```
{
  title     => 'Liste des machines',
  msg       => { get_flash() },
  computers => \@computers
};
```

The reference prevents the hash being flattened into a list. Your data structure will look like this:

```
{
  title     => 'Liste des machines',
  msg       => { one => 1, two => 2 },
  computers => \@computers
};
```

(Pedantically, the problem is that subroutines don't return hashes - they return lists. The list only becomes a hash when you store it in a hash variable.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I test this solution with reference but not work... Do you think of my template foreach is correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I understood the problem. This is my get_flash() function, indeed when I remove the "msg" element the showing is ok. So I have forget my reference and the "get_flash" function is bad. Thanks you for your help.

Comment: Is it perhaps possible that your call to `get_flash()` is returning more than one value?

Comment: The return of get_flash() is a Hashmap. I think I'm not use correctly the return of get_flash. But for the moment It's works :) Thank you for your help.

Comment: If `get_flash()` returns a hash, then you need to take a reference to it before putting in your template hash. `msg => { get_flash() }`.

Comment: @Oneill: I think I've explained the problem in the updated version of my answer.